# Why does sorting does not work when I go to another paging?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pagination

Still new and beginner at asp.net. I wonder why sorting does not work when i changed to another paging? I sorted in page 1, but when i go to page 2 the sort seems not working.

What i want is when i click the header, it will sort all way to the last page and does not break when changing the paging.

This code works, but when i changed the paging, the sort breaks or not working. I still see data that should be in page 1 not in page 2.

tblaccount is a asp:gridview, Sorting and Paging is set to True.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //populateCDA();

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                refreshdata();
            }

        }

        private void populateCDA()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            // get the connection    
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(mc.defaultConnection))
            {
                // write the sql statement to execute    
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[GETACCOUNTS]()";
                // instantiate the command object to fire    
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    // get the adapter object and attach the command object to it    
                    using (SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        // fire Fill method to fetch the data and fill into DataTable    
                        ad.Fill(table);
                    }
                }
            }
            // specify the data source for the GridView    
            tblViewAccount.DataSource = table;
            // bind the data now    
            tblViewAccount.DataBind();
        }

        public void refreshdata()
        {
            
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mc.defaultConnection);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[GETACCOUNTS]()", con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            tblViewAccount.DataSource = dt;
            tblViewAccount.DataBind();
            ViewState["dirState"] = dt;
            ViewState["sortdr"] = "Asc";


        }

        protected void tblViewAccount_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dtrslt = (DataTable)ViewState["dirState"];
            if (dtrslt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["sortdr"]) == "Asc")
                {
                    dtrslt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " Desc";
                    ViewState["sortdr"] = "Desc";
                }
                else
                {
                    dtrslt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " Asc";
                    ViewState["sortdr"] = "Asc";
                }
                tblViewAccount.DataSource = dtrslt;
                tblViewAccount.DataBind();


            }
        }

        protected void tblViewAccount_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            tblViewAccount.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            tblViewAccount.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: Paging happens before sorting. So, if you have 1 5 4 2 3 6 and page size is 3, you get Page 1: 1 4 5 and Page 2: 2 3 6. While you expect 1 2 3 and 4 5 6, right?

Comment: Yes. However I get Page 1: 6 5 4 and Page 2:  4 5 6, sorting stop or only work on the current page using the code above. Clicking the header in the current page sort the current page but not the rest of the paging.

Comment: Ok, that's odd ... then there is more to it than just order of steps.

Comment: I wanted it to be in order not just a single page or the page 1, but the rest of the paging.

Comment: Explain to us what `dtrslt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " Desc";` is trying to achieve. If you put a breakpoint on that line, is it hit when reversing sort order? Is it getting hit when you switch pages? Might https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643474/maintain-sorting-with-paging-in-a-gridview be helpful in your context?

Comment: Yes, with your example, it's clear. Maybe you could add such an example to the question, so people know what's happening there.

Comment: This code will pull down **all** accounts on _every page_. Look into the `OFFSET` and `FETCH` keywords to make the paging process easier and _much_ more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

When you page - you have to re-bind grid to the table.

So try this:

```
DataTable dtrslt = (DataTable)ViewState["dirState"];
tblViewAccount.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
tblViewAccount.DataSource = dtrslt;    
tblViewAccount.DataBind();
```